# Paypal REST SDK - Billing Plans no longer retrievable after being made ACTIVE

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

So I'm using the Paypal PHP SDK on Github, http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/ . Some strange behavior I've noticed which I'm not sure what's going on.

So let's say I create a billing plan, but don't touch it after creation, so that the state is simple CREATED. Everything is good, I can retrieve it from the list of plans. However, the moment I change the state to ACTIVE via a patch, I can see that it is in fact active, but only just once.  Any subsequent attempts to see the list of plans no longer shows that plan.  What's going on?  I'm literally copy pasting the example source they give.

Edit - just to expand, I know the plan still exists, because I can subscribe users to it.  Weirdly the paypal page where you click ok to subscribe is extremely non verbose... doesn't even say what the price is, just to approve paying my store.  And yet the Agreement object that is returned by PayPal, which includes the approval url, has all this info.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the PayPal-PHP-SDK, you could assign more parameters to Plan::all() method.

As shown in the [List Plan sample code](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/billing/ListPlans.html), you could pass parameter 'status' as :

```
try {
    // Get the list of all plans
    // You can modify different params to change the return list.
    // The explanation about each pagination information could be found here
    // at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#list-plans
    $params = array('page_size' => '20', 'page' => '98', 'status' => 'ACTIVE');
    $planList = Plan::all($params, $apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    ResultPrinter::printError("List of Plans", "Plan", null, $params, $ex);
    exit(1);
}
```

[image]

As in the case, you could change the `status`, and `page` along with `page_size`. This will help you get the active list of plans.

Actually, by default the [list plan](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#list-plans) `status` is defaulted to `CREATED`.